# ASMX - Web Method not getting invoked on IIS

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, asmx

I am using **asmx** webservice. Its working fine in my working environment. But, If I published into IIS, getting 404 - Page Not Found Error .

> `http://localhost/ReportService/RService.asmx/MyWebMethod`

At the same time I am able to view the web methods in browser by the URL,

> `http://localhost/ReportService/RService.asmx?wsdl`

Please help me to resolve this.

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: is the IIS instance on a remote server?

Comment: try 
http://localhost/ReportService/RService.asmx

Comment: Nope. In Local machine only.

Comment: Go to IIS and browse the service and see if it works fine. Also make sure your hosted service is running under right frame work. Go to site properties > ASP.NET and check the framework.

Comment: as @Damith pointed out, remove the **?wsdl**, you should have a webpage with hyperlinks to your methods. Click on the method you want to invoke, and you will see a button there to **invoke**

Answer (score 0):

> 404 - Page Not Found Error

You might receive this for number of reasons, Make sure to

- Go to IIS and browse the service and see if it works fine. Also make sure your hosted service is running under right frame work. Go to site properties > `ASP.NET` and check the `framework`.
- Go into IIS Manager -> Servername -> "`Web Service Extensions`", and set ASP.NET version that you use to Allowed